# Calling a jQuery function using a variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where MODE is a variable. Its value should be a method of jQuery's tinycolor liberary.

```
$cor = tinycolor($cor).mode(z).toString();
```

I'd like to call that method on that line so, for instance, when mode = 'lighten' $cor would be

```
$cor = tinycolor($cor).lighten(z).toString();
```

Is there a way of doing it this way?

Thanks!

Comment: use arrays to name variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bracket notation

```
$cor = tinycolor($cor)[mode](z).toString();
```

Comment: oh! Wasn't aware of that! Awesome, thanks